# How to pass URL for dynamically generated anchor tags to jQuery hover() function??

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

Hi What I am trying to do here is I am generating a list of Links in HTML as Anchor tags:

```
<a href="/path/100" id="clickme">One link</a>
<a href="/path/101" id="clickme">Sec link</a>
<a href="/path/102" id="clickme">Third link</a>
<a href="/path/103" id="clickme">Fourth link</a>
```

I want to fire `Ajax` call to the specific URL when someone hovers on any of the link. So I am registering a `hover()` function like this for this id:

```
$('#clickme').hover(function(){
         $.ajax({
                beforeSend : function(jqXHR){
                    //Doin something
                },
                url: //should be the url from the anchor tag that fired this event(how to get it??),
                success: function(data) {
                    //Doin something
                },
                error: function(jqXHR){
                    //Doin something
                }
              });
        });
```

My Question is How can I pass the anchor tag as an object or something so that i can retrieve anything i want like `href`, position of the link etc..

For single anchor tag it is working but for multiplle not..Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id should always be unique (that is why it is called ID) .. make it class and use class selector

**html**

```
<a href="/path/100" class="clickme">One link</a>
<a href="/path/101" class="clickme">Sec link</a>
<a href="/path/102" class="clickme">Third link</a>
<a href="/path/103" class="clickme">Fourth link</a>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.clickme').hover(function(){
     var $this=$(this);
     $.ajax({
            beforeSend : function(jqXHR){
                //Doin something
            },
            url: //should be the url from the anchor tag that fired this event(how to get it??),
            data:{'href':$this.attr('href')}, //this will send '/path/100' as href if u click first link 
            success: function(data) {
                //Doin something
            },
            error: function(jqXHR){
                //Doin something
            }
          });
    });
```

Comment: Ok but inside my hover function how to get that particular anchor tag details?

Comment: Can't i directly give `url:$this.attr('href')` ??

Comment: yes.. u can....that means the link that is there in the <a>  href tag will be calle dby the ajax...

Answer (score 1):

You should use class instead of using same id for multiple object and use `this.href` for each object. Assigning same id to more then one html elements is not allowed, though you can do it.

```
<a href="/path/100" id="clickme" class="someclass">One link</a>
<a href="/path/101" id="clickme" class="someclass">Sec link</a>
<a href="/path/102" id="clickme" class="someclass">Third link</a>
<a href="/path/103" id="clickme" class="someclass">Fourth link</a>


$('.someclass').hover(function(){
     $.ajax({
            beforeSend : function(jqXHR){
                //Doin something
            },
            url: //should be the url from the anchor tag that fired this event(how to get it??),
            success: function(data) {
                //Doin something
            },
            error: function(jqXHR){
                //Doin something
            }
          });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because ID's are unique, and jQuery will only find the first instance of an ID.

```
<a href="/path/100" class="clickme">One link</a>
<a href="/path/101" class="clickme">Sec link</a>
<a href="/path/102" class="clickme">Third link</a>
<a href="/path/103" class="clickme">Fourth link</a>
```

js

```
$('.clickme').mouseenter(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
         url : href
    });
});
```

Comment: What will be the advantages of using `mouseenter` over `hover`??

Comment: @Anubhab - jQuery's hover() function is just a shortcut for mouseenter and mouseleave, and you are only using the mouseenter part, so why not just drop the extra function call and use mouseenter directly.

Comment: I am using version 1.4.2. Could you please suggest a different way of handling this? because `on` function was added in version `1.7`

Comment: Yeah dat i can do..I have found another solution and that is instead of `hover` i am using `mouseenter`. :)

Comment: @Anubhab - Gee, did you read the answer above and notice what event it uses?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` inside if your hover event handler to get the href attribute. And the other answers are correct about using class instead of id. The example below is set to use a class of 'clickme' instead of an id.

```
$('.clickme').hover(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var theUrl = $this.attr('href');

     $.ajax({
            beforeSend : function(jqXHR){
                //Doin something
            },
            url: theUrl
            success: function(data) {
                //Doin something
            },
            error: function(jqXHR){
                //Doin something
            }
          });
    });
```