# How do you open a URL in a dialog box JQUERY UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've been looking for a simple solution for quite some time. I want a page (for example http://www.google.com) to be displayed in a JQuery UI Dialog window. The plan is to later add the URL dynamically so all links from my site will be displayed in said window.

I tried the following, but the dialog window is empty when clicking on the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>


<meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#openwindow').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<a id="openwindow" href="http://www.google.com">Click me to test.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I found a few examples, but none actually worked. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically you want an ajax call is it?

Answer (score 15):

You don't need an `iframe` as has been suggested, but you should read the documentation on dialogs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Instead, you need to load the content on the `.open` property --

```
$( "#openwindow" ).dialog({
 open: function(event, ui) {
   $('#divInDialog').load('test.html', function() {
     alert('Load was performed.');
   });
  }
});
```

Also, you seem to use `.each` with an `id` -- the `id` is supposed to be unique within the page. use `class` instead.

Comment: You can't use `.load()` if the URL is in another domain, because of cross-domain AJAX restrictions.

Answer (score 7):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div/>', {'class':'myDlgClass', 'id':'link-'+($(this).index()+1)})
        .load($(this).attr('href')).appendTo('body').dialog();
    });
});
```

Above code will create a new `dialog` on clicking on any link on your page and also add a class name `myDlgClass` and an unique id for each dialog like `link-1`, `link-2` and so on, but remember that only page link will be loaded not external link because of same origin policy.

### Update :

To use an external site link you can use  an `iframe`, here is [an example using iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/NSmkC/).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409243/how-to-pass-url-for-dynamically-generated-anchor-tags-to-jquery-hover-function/)
might help.. Here what i am doing is i am hovering on a link and the url is opening in a dialog box..
You should use `class` instead of `id` if multiple same tags are getting created dynamically..ohterwise it will work for only single `id`.

```
$('.openwindow').click(function(){
var $this=$(this);
         $.ajax({
                url: $this.attr('href');//You got the link here
                success: function(data) {
                    //show the dialog here..
                    //"data" contains the html returned by the url
                },
                error: function(jqXHR){
                    //Do something here
                }
              });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe:

```
 $("#iframeId").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
 $('#dialogId').dialog('open');
```

```
<div id="divId" >
    <IFRAME id="iframeId"  SRC="" width="" height = "" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but none of the above suggestions worked for me.  After much investigation, I found this very simple solution.  Add a link object to the document, set the href param on it, and click it, programmatically.  No iframe, no dialog, just the download.  I needed to fetch a signed S3 url based on user action on the page and provide for the download of the file.  I wasn't allowed to populate the page with signatures that would last a long time.  Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: actionUrl,
    complete: function(data) {
        var signedS3url = data.responseText;
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.href=signedS3url;
        link.click();                               
    }
});
```