# JQuery Dialog Box with HTML Contents

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

Im having problems with dialog box. I wanted to display inside the Dialog box the HTML content of the another page. for example.

index.php

```
 var url = "/leave_ot/statistics.php?what="+type+"&item="+applicant;
   //alert(url);

    $.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : url,
        success : function(result)
        {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                height: 140,
                modal: true
            });
        }
    })
```

applicant.html

```
some html codes
```

I wanted to put the html contents of applicant.html into the dialog box of index.php

Comment: And what happens? Error messages in console? What? Where do you process result?

Comment: @mplungjan Read the code, you can see what happens: it doesn't insert anything anywhere.

Comment: If you want `applicant.html`, why does the URL point to `statistics.php`?

Comment: @Barmar True - I just wanted to explain the user to add such info to the question

Comment: `$("#id_where_the_content_to_be_displayed").html(result);$("#dialog")...`

Comment: my bad, i forgot to change statistics to applicant.html

Comment: answer of this question is already given see link below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459107/how-do-you-open-a-url-in-a-dialog-box-jquery-ui

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.html()` method to insert the HTML result into the DIV.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    url     : url,
    success : function(result)
    {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
        }).html(result);
    }
});
```

Note that this only works if the URL is in the same domain; cross-domain AJAX prevents using it for other domains. If you need that, you'll have to use an IFRAME; see the answers in [How do you open a URL in a dialog box JQUERY UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459107/how-do-you-open-a-url-in-a-dialog-box-jquery-ui)