# Popupwindow should stick to the main window

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

I have a onclick event in the main window. On clicking, a popup is opened using `window.open(someurl.com)`. In the popup(someurl.com) there is a clickable item. When that item is clicked it opens the url in a new tab. When that new tab is now closed the popup windows does not remain in focus. Instead the main window is in focus and the popup goes behind the main window. What I want is, when the tab (which is opened from the popup) is closed the popup should get focus and not the main window. Is that possible? Please help me in how to achieve this? The important thing is, I do not have control on the popup url. It is an external url which is not in my control.
Thank you,

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: @AmilaIddamalgoda, The relevant piece of code is in my original post. window.open(someurl.com). I do not have control on someurl.com.

Comment: i think it is impossible, you can try with jquery ui dialog. here is the reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/15459179/2567813 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14021220/2567813

Comment: It should be possible. I came across a website which had the same intended behviour that I wanted. I do not recollect which website was that. But I think certainly doable...

Comment: Any suggestions that I can try.

Answer (score 6):

May be this will work:-
`var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");`
`myWindow.focus();`