# JQuery ui modal dialog external ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to load another page in a jquery ui modal

This is my Js File

```
function eventWindow(url) {
    getElementById("eventviewer").style.display="block";
    $("#eventviewer").load(url).dialog({
      modal:true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
}
```

this the markup

```
    <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title><?php echo "Date:".$firstDayArray['month']." ".$firstDayArray['year'];?>
        </title>
        <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        .....
    <?php
        echo "<td class=\"days\"><a href=\"javascript:eventWindow('events.php?m=".$month."&d=".$dayArray["mday"]."&y=$year');\">".$dayArray["mday"]."</a><br/>".$event_title."</td>\n";
    ?>
<div id="eventviewer"></div>
        ......
        </body
        </html>
```

when i use window.open it works and opens in separate window.

But i am not able to open it in a jquery ui modal dialog.

Comment: SO You are trying to add html page in dialog

Comment: yes.. when the link is clicked event.php is called

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459107/how-do-you-open-a-url-in-a-dialog-box-jquery-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this but I am not sure which one is the best practice. You can append an iFrame in the dialog container like this:

```
$("#dialog").append($("<iframe />").attr("src", "your link")).dialog({dialogoptions});
```

**OR:**

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/H7uar/479/)**

```
$(function () {
    var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        close: function () {
            iframe.attr("src", "");
        }
    });
    $(".thumb a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var src = $(this).attr("href");
        var title = $(this).attr("data-title");
        var width = $(this).attr("data-width");
        var height = $(this).attr("data-height");
        iframe.attr({
            width: +width,
            height: +height,
            src: src
        });
        dialog.dialog("option", "title", title).dialog("open");
    });
});
```